# Is it possible to recover the password from bitcoin.core other than guessing?

Tags: bitcoin-core

У меня есть монеты в кошельке биткой коре,есть дат файл и знаю что пароль из 12 заглавных английских букв и знаю seed phrase, как мне сделать транзакцию или вастоновить кошелек, пароль?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't recover the password from Bitcoin core or from any of its data files.

If you could, so could thieves.

---

If you know the seed phrase (also known as a recovery phrase) you can create a new wallet from that seed phrase. Your wallet software should provide a means of doing this.

For example, there is [a description of the process for Electrum](https://bitcoinelectrum.com/restoring-your-standard-wallet-from-seed/).